# Excel - SUMIF next cell color is

Tags: excel, sumifs

I need to SUM values from cells B5:B10 if C5:C10 background color is red.

So lets say C5 and C8 are red, I need SUM from cells B5+B8.

These are the modules that I've used: http://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/sum-cells-based-on-background-color/

This is not working: =SUMIF(C5:C10;"="&GetCellColor(C5:C10)="="&GetCellColor(A1);B5:B10)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

GetCellColor

```
Function GetCellColor(xlRange As Range)
Dim indRow, indColumn As Long
Dim arResults()

Application.Volatile

If xlRange Is Nothing Then
    Set xlRange = Application.ThisCell
End If

If xlRange.Count > 1 Then
  ReDim arResults(1 To xlRange.Rows.Count, 1 To xlRange.Columns.Count)
   For indRow = 1 To xlRange.Rows.Count
     For indColumn = 1 To xlRange.Columns.Count
       arResults(indRow, indColumn) = xlRange(indRow, indColumn).Interior.Color
     Next
   Next
 GetCellColor = arResults
Else
 GetCellColor = xlRange.Interior.Color
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Can you post your UDF?

Comment: I agree. Please *edit* your question, **add GetCellColor()**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if you have colors in any contiguous vertical range with the values in the preceding column and you are only looking for the color red:

```
Function CountAdjacent(colorRange As Range) As Long

Dim clr As Variant
Dim countValue As Long

For Each clr In colorRange
    If clr.Interior.color = vbRed Then
        countValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(clr.Offset(0, -1).Value, countValue)
    End If
Next clr
CountAdjacent = countValue

End Function
```

Type `=CountAdjacent(yourColorRange)` in a cell like any other formula.